# wordpress warnings showing even when turned off

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings, mamp

I know this question has been asked a kazillion times, but I've read the responses and done all suggestions. My phpinfo shows:

```
display_errors = off
error_reporting = 0
```

and I've set all of the suggestions in my config file, e.g.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

and yet I'm STILL getting warnings like the following:

```
Warning: Parameter 1 to wp_default_scripts() expected to be a reference, value given in /Users/.../wp-includes/plugin.php on line 601
Warning: Parameter 1 to wp_default_styles() expected to be a reference, value given in /Users/.../wp-includes/plugin.php on line 601
```

Please note, I'm using MAMP for a local server and wordpress. Also I've searched the entire site to see if WP_DEBUG is being set elsewhere and it's not.

I'm banging my head against a wall. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Heather

Answer (score 3):

Which version of php and Wordpress are you running? There are several posts in the wordpress core tracker pointing similar issues with php 7.1:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38144

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37772

Regarding why is WP showing this warnings although you have disabled all debug options here are some suggestions:

- Search in your php.ini for something like this and comment it:

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ER… _ERROR
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

- Search your code for `error_reporting(whatever)` or `ini_set('error_reporting', whatever);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! You were right about the PHP version - I set it back to 7.0 and now the warnings don't show!
However, re:error_reporting variable, my phpinfo shows error_reporting=0 so regardless of what it is set in any files, it is set to 0 and therefore none should show, right?

Comment: error_reporting() sets the error_reporting directive at runtime so I think it will report errors regardless your php.ini configuration. Some users on php.net point that the directive display_errors must be set On at php.ini in order to show errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php